# Bootstrap 3: dynamic form, inserting additional textarea fields from browser

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Meteor 0.9.1 /
accounts-password /
accounts-ui /
iron:router /
mizzao:bootstrap-3

My Aim: Enable a user to build a questionnaire and save it into their user profile.

Features:

1. A button that renders another textarea for the user to write another question.
2. Save all the questions into the users' profile collection after pressing the 'save' button.

With the following code, I am able to retrieve the data from the input id 'question1' and make it available for the method function which I need help to write.

HTML:

```
<template name="questionnaire">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="createquestion">
    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="question" >Question</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input  class="form-control" type="text" id="question1" value="" placeholder="type your question here..."/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">+ another question</button>
    <input  type="submit" value="save">
</form></template>
```

client.js:

```
Template.questionnaire.events({
'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var qdata = {
        question: $(e.target).find('#question1').val()
    }
    Meteor.call('insertQdata', qdata);
} });
```

Can you suggest how to save all the questions into an array of the field 'questions' within user profile?

Thank you

Comment: how about trying to use SessionStorage. https://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/

Comment: I will look into this further Satya after I'm able to achieve function 1. Unless the doc you provided integrates into function 1, I'm challenged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at autoform: https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/autoform . It has bootstrap support built in so everything will look nice!

You can define a schema like so:

```
questionSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    questions: {
        type: [String],
        label: "Question"
    }
});
```

Then you insert your form somewhere using something like the following code (look at the autoform docs for further information):

```
{{#autoForm schema=questionSchema id="someId" type="method" meteormethod="insertData"}}
{{> afQuickField name="questions"}}
{{/autoForm}}
```

Then finally in your meteor method you do the following:

```
insertData: function(doc){
    Meteor.user().questions = doc.questions;
}
```

That should do the the job without too much of a hassle about adding additional buttons. I haven't tested the code, so if you run into problems, please leave a comment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I have installed autoform and unable to get your example  working. 

I need help to achieve the following example. If you can show me how with autoform that will be fantastic. Each text area will a string element saved into an array inside the users profile field 'questions'

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dynamic-form-fields-add-amp-remove

Comment: Error: AutoForm: form with id "someId" needs either "schema" or "collection" attribute
    at Object.getSimpleSchemaFromContext

//Is the schema placed inside the template helper or in the collections.js file?

Comment: I forgot something. Where you place the schema doesn't matter, as long as it is a global variable (without the var like I wrote it). But you have to have another template helper that is called questionSchema and return the schema. Then it should be fine.

Comment: Template.questionnaire.events({
    'submit form': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Meteor.call('insertQdata', something);
    }
});

Where I wrote 'something', that needs to be there and is the data I need to pass to the method. How do I retrieve the data(questions)? There is nothing is being inserted into the user profile

Comment: You don't need that bit. just put: Template.questionnaire.helpers({questionSchema: function(){return questionSchema}})

You don't to do something when the user submits, autoform handles that for you. You just need to write the meteor method that you passed as the method-parameter for autoform.

Comment: Thank you greatly for your help so far, just for the record, autoform is not displaying its own submit button which is why I added it.

Comment: Yes, you have to add your submit button but you don't have to do the event handling yourself. If this helped you, please accept and upvote my answer. Thank you

Comment: I used the following update code from your previous help and it works!! thank you!!!

insertData: function(doc){
    Meteor.users.update( { _id: Meteor.userId() }, { $addToSet: { 'profile.questions': doc }} );
}
});

Comment: I've been reading through the docs and unable to no insert these questions to a new collection  /   AllQuestions = new Meteor.Collection('allquestions')

Has this got something to do with insecure being removed?

My autoform method is //    insertData: function(doc){
    AllQuestions = doc.questions;
}
});

Comment: You cannot just do collection = insertData. You have to use a valid Mongo command. It does not have to do with insecure, that is just relevant for the client. Have a look at the docs for mongo.insert